# Find assembly version from a web part solution

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to find the assembly version of a web part solution in sharepoint (via powershell)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code sample:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("AssemblyNameWithoutSuffix")
```

Comment: Thanks, from the FullName property I can get the version